# Query slow in SSRS but fast in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

i've got the following query:

```
    SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ResultsA.Followup = 1 THEN ResultsA.Auditors END) as ColumnResults,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ResultsA.UnannInspectionYN = 1 THEN ResultsA.Auditors END) ColumnResults2,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ResultsA.UnannInspectionYN = 0 AND ResultsA.Followup = 0 THEN ResultsA.Auditors END) ColumnResults3,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ResultsA.Auditors) ColumnResults4
FROM 
    ResultsA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.Auditors = ResultsA.Auditors 
    INNER JOIN TableC ON TableC.TableCColumn = ResultsA.TableCColumn AND Country IN (@Country)
WHERE 
exists(Select SupData 
                  from IMP_SUP_DATA 
                  where impID = @id and TableC.TableCColumn = SupData)
AND
    TableB.ColumnA in ( 'Accepted and reviewed' , 'Accepted, but not reviewed', 'Submitted', 'Accepted (provisional)')
AND 
    TableB.Date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
AND 
    ISNULL(TableC.Datainfo,'No Data') IN (@Datainfo)
```

The query pulls from quite a bit of data, but when I run it in SSMS it's very fast. I can go back years and the query still returns within ~10 seconds at max. 
However, when i run the query as a report, it can take up to minutes and even time-out at some results.

How can i solve this in the best manner? I'm hoping to learn from this to prevent it happening in the future. The environment is sql server 2014.

Comment: Take a look on this article: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: I used that as original reference, but unfortunately (it may be me) I couldn't find the result there.

Comment: Create a dataset in SSRS with this sql: `DBCC USEROPTIONS` and compare the output with the same command executed in SSMS. Perhaps some SET options are enabled in SSMS and missing in SSRS connection

Comment: The settings are the same, I just checked.. Can you help me optimize my query?

Comment: can you please let us know if your issue was resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*OP mentioned in the comment that problem is not related to different SET options of connections in SSMS and SSRS*

First of all, makes sense to confirm that the issue is in data retrieval operation by running the report and querying then catalog database:

```
USE ReportServer
SELECT TOP 100 ReportPath, TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing, TimeRendering 
FROM dbo.ExecutionLog2
ORDER BY TimeStart desc
```

The value of `TimeDataRetrieval` should take majority of the entire duration

If this is a case and the same query with the same parameters runs fast in SSMS and slow in SSRS consider such changes:

- Add explicit CAST of variables to exact type as type of corresponding column in table
- Remove ISNULL() in WHERE clause
- Add OPTION RECOMPILE, since this is a parameterized resource intensive query

Following query to be evaluated (but firstly, CASTs to be adjusted to  right data types):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ResultsA.Followup = 1 THEN ResultsA.Auditors END) as ColumnResults,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ResultsA.UnannInspectionYN = 1 THEN ResultsA.Auditors END) ColumnResults2,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ResultsA.UnannInspectionYN = 0 AND ResultsA.Followup = 0 THEN ResultsA.Auditors END) ColumnResults3,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ResultsA.Auditors) ColumnResults4
FROM 
    ResultsA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.Auditors = ResultsA.Auditors 
    INNER JOIN TableC ON TableC.TableCColumn = ResultsA.TableCColumn AND Country IN (CAST(@Country AS VARCHAR(255)) )
WHERE 
EXISTS (Select SupData 
                  from IMP_SUP_DATA 
                  where impID = CAST(@id AS INT) and TableC.TableCColumn = SupData)

AND    TableB.ColumnA in ( 'Accepted and reviewed' , 'Accepted, but not reviewed', 'Submitted', 'Accepted (provisional)')

AND    TableB.Date BETWEEN CAST(@FromDate AS DATETIME) AND CAST(@ToDate AS DATETIME)
AND    ( TableC.Datainfo IN (CAST(@Datainfo AS VARCHAR(255))) OR ( CAST(@Datainfo AS VARCHAR(255))  = 'No Data' AND TableC.Datainfo IS NULL))
OPTION ( RECOMPILE)
```